# mysqli_query Return Value and Set as $variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this is probably going to be a very simple answer, but I can't seem to figure this out! I'm a newbie when it comes to mysqli_query.

Example.

$con = my connection variable.
In database the Row id = 5

```
$post_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM posts SET id as '$post_id"');
echo $post_id
```

If I were to echo $post_id now it would return 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you learn that syntax from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling mysqli_query returns a [mysqli_result object](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) - not a string. So you need to loop through the results of your query. This query will get all rows where the id of the post is the same as `$post_id`.

```
$post_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id = '.$post_id.'");

while ($row = $post_id->fetch_assoc())
{
    foreach($row as $value) echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
```

You'd probably want to change the name of the variable from `$post_id` to something a bit more generic but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're getting an SQL error. But assuming your SQL is right, you have to fetch the results like this:

```
$sql = "select 99 id, 'Peter' name"; //this SQL throws a single row
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
//if you expect only 1 row:
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['id']; //output: 99
echo $row['name']; //output: Peter
```

Comment: is what you posted as a query, actually the "real" php syntax here? *Maybe* in phpmyadmin but not in php.

Comment: `select 99 id, 'Peter' name` that will throw a syntax error. I don't know where you got those words/names from, it's totally different than the OP's. Have a look at XanT's answer; that is the correct syntax.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: About that code generating error: No, it won't using mysqli. It's the same if you execute it in phpmyadmin or using mysqli. I'm saying: bring me 99 as value of field 'id' and 'Peter' as value as field 'name'. No error.

About "where did I got that data": Can't you tell it's fake data? My point is how to FETCH the data. Read my answer, I wrote: "assuming your SQL is right..." I don't care about the SQL sentence itself.